# If I assign the same value twice (to the same variable), will the statement be ignored?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, variable-assignment

For example,

```
int i = 0;

i = new Random().Next();
```

If `new Random().Next();` returns `0` will the CLR notice the unnecessary assignment and not execute the statement, or will the statement still execute anyway?

Comment: The _compiler_ might just remove the `= 0;` assignment as `i` is immediately overwritten. But the CLR will still assign the zero from the `Random().Next();` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will we executed and assigned anyway. CLR will not do this kind of optimizations. Usually JIT will do optimizations but not in this case.

I don't think this kind of optimizations will be implemented either.

Consider for all the assignments you're going to execute if compiler checks whether old value equals new value and skips will degrade the performance very much. That will impact on performance more if you have `overridden` `Equals` and do some computationally expensive checks for determining the equality. This hurts. Isn't it?

Once I've written a benchmark to see whether *checking the same value and ignore assignment is better* or *overwriting the value blindly is better*. Results says *overwriting the value blindly is better*. Am not having the code right now interested people can try themselves and evaluate the result.